# I have a multidimensional object which I want to foreach through in Javascript, but I'm not able to get "deep enough" to get the value I want

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

What I want to do is that the code below should write "Hey amber :)" and "Hello Patrick :)", but it just gives me an empty result.

```
var messages2 =
{
    "name":"svdMsgs","args":
    [{
        "messages":[
        {"msg":"Hey amber :)","toId":1276},
        {"msg":"Hello patrick :)","toId":1}]
    }]
}



for (var key in messages2.args.messages)
{
  var obj = messages2.args.messages[key];
  document.write(obj['msg']);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to inspect each property/element step by step, i.e. , `messages.args`, `messages.args[0]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is an array - it doesn't have a member named `messages`.

You'll have to try

```
messages2.args[0].messages
```

Comment: Worked absolutely perfect. Thank you very much!  : )